# Error when deploying a node.js app on a PLESK ONYX server with Phusion Passenger V. 5.3.5

Tags: node.js, express, passenger, phusion, plesk-onyx

I want to deploy a small node.js app on a PLESK-ONYX server - on which Phusion_Passenger / 5.3.5 is also running!

The following happens:

**This works here:**

```
var express = require ('express');

var bodyParser = require ('body-parser');
```

**That does not work:**

```
import express from 'express';

import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
```

**The following error then occurs:**

The Phusion Passenger application server tried to start the web application through a Passenger-internal helper tool called the "wrapper". But Passenger was unable to execute that helper tool because it encountered an internal error.

```
The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is:

/var/www/vhosts/hosting13.netcup.net/mem3-s3.hxxx-3.de/index.js:2

import express from 'express';

    ^^^^^^^
```

How can one solve it?

Where is the problem?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Best regards

Markus

---

Hello, I have new findings in the meantime ...

my problem seems to be - that the highest-available node.js version in PLESK at the moment is 12.4!

In PLESK - i must start the node.js-App with a server.js-File - like this:

```
const app = require('./index.mjs');
const http = require('http');

http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT);
```

My node.js-Version is V.12.4 so i must use esm like this:

```
require = require("esm")(module/*, options*/)
module.exports = require("./index.js")
```

How can i combine the 2 files in the right way?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Here is the content of "package.json":

```
{
  "name": "mb-test-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.mjs",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon -r esm index.mjs"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv":"^8.2.0",
    "esm":"^3.2.25",
    "express":"^4.17.1",
    "mongoose":"^5.9.29",
    "nodemon":"^2.0.7"
  }

}
```

But unfortunately I haven't found yet - where in PLESK the start command for node.js can be edited!

Best regards

Markus

Answer (score 0):

for using `import` `from` you should change type in package.json to `module` so add this code to the package.json

```
"type": "module"
```

**Note:** but export file is different between `commonjs` and `module`.

by default type is `commonjs` , check this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/#:%7E:text=While%20CommonJS%20and%20ES6%20modules,demand%20while%20executing%20the%20code.)

you can also using babel module, update scripts in package.json like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist/ && babel ./ --out-dir dist/ --ignore ./node_modules,./.babelrc,./package.json,./npm-debug.log --copy-files",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/app.js"
  }
```

after that for running project

```
npm start
```

Comment: Hello, the line "type": "module" is in the package.json - but it doesn't work!